# Get Value From Panels Within A UserControl

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, panel

I have a user control that consist multiple panels. Each panel have a question, multiple buttons to select and textboxes. On the main form, there's a button to pull all the answers from the panels so it can be stored to a table.
I can't figure out the best way to do this. Below is what the panels looks like:
[image]

Since they all from different panel, I'm thinking of using the get/set properties, but not sure if it will work. Please tell me there are better ideas to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a property (e.g. `Public ReadOnly Property Results`) on your UserControl that returns a data structure of some kind (a List (Of T) of a custom class, a DataTable, whatever). Then, consumers of your UserControl can access the whole set of (questions and) answers via this property.

```
Dim x as MyResults = myUserControlOfQuestions.Results
' Do something with MyResults to store to the database.
```